# Finding consecutive characters in a 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector

I need a function to replace all of the consecutive characters with '*'. 
I have this 2D vector (`vector<vector< string > > two_dimensional( row, vector < string >( col )` ) :

```
r   g   o   g   b   

r   r   r   r   r   

g   r   r   b   o   

y   y   r   o   g
```

How can i make a function to compare for example vec[ 1 ][ 2 ] with all elements of row 1 and col 2, and result in following :

```
r   g   o   g   b   

*   *   *   *   *   

g   r   *   b   o   

y   y   *   o   g
```

I'm tired of segmentation fault errors so help me out please!

Comment: Why do you have a `vector` of a `vector`? Why not just a `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: _'I'm tired of segmentation fault errors so help me out please!'_ Which specific ones please? Show the code you have tried.

Comment: @remyabel : as I've said it's a TWO Dimensional vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something as the following (without testing)

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::size_type size_type;
void replace( std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> &v, size_type row, size_type col )
{
   if ( v.size() <= row ) return;
   if ( v[row].size() <= col ) return;

   std::string value = v[row][col];

   for ( size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
   {
      if ( col < v[i].size() && v[i][col] == value ) v[i][col] = "*";
   }


   for ( std::string &s : v[row] )
   {
      if ( s == value ) s = "*";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your example it looks like you intend to replace adjacent values on the horizontal and vertical axes. This is the only explanation why the 'r' value in last row was modified. However, your example still has errors in the output. It should look something like the following.

```
r g o g b 
* * * * * 
g * * b o 
y * * o g
```

If you are intending to check for adjacent values in the x and y axis you will need to retain the original value at a given point until both axes have been checked. The easiest way to do this is just keep the original matrix as read-only and create a new modified matrix. Below is a sample function that will work. [A working example of this can be found here](http://ideone.com/2yZfK3).

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<char>> two_dimensional;

two_dimensional remove_adjacents(const two_dimensional& source)
{
    two_dimensional modified = source;
    const size_t rowSize = source.size();
    const size_t colSize = rowSize > 0 ? source[0].size() : 0;
    for(size_t row = 0; row < rowSize; ++row)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < colSize; ++col)
        {
            if(row > 0 && source[row][col] == source[row-1][col])
                modified[row][col] = '*';
            if(col > 0 && source[row][col] == source[row][col-1])
                modified[row][col] = '*';
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```